Run tasks from other dag from a parent dag
Is there any way to run a particular task of a dag from another dag? I need to clear TaskA from dag1 using dag2.
I know there is a cli command that clears and reruns the tasks. But I need it implemented inside the airflow code.

You could enabled and use the Airflow API :
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_clear_task_instances
OR you could also try to use direct the task instance object
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c53a3e153f0ab5ca933a94adc01dc6314ea8d4d1/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L167
